# What happens if the password of the API user to connect the clouds expires?

Tags: marketing-cloud, user, marketing-cloud-connect, passwords

I know, I would get unauthorized errors but does it happens instantly?

I mean, if I have a journey connected and the password expires, does it stop instantly? Does it finish? How long will take for all the processes to error?

Thanks

Comment: To be honest, in none of the implementations I have worked on, has this been an issue. You should design your solution appropriately, so none of your integration users (who for sure should be dedicated integration users - no shortcuts here) have passwords which expire.

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008lDfIAI maybe this might answer your query.